# How to add some one time initiation code in robolectric tests

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric

How to add some one time initiation code in robolectric Android tests.

We can add like Some method with @Before annotation which would run before the tests of that class run but can wee add some code that is executed one before any test code is executed, in Android robolectric.

Comment: Can you give example why @before is not enough?

Comment: Do you need it to run once before all the tests in the class or do you need it to run once before all the tests in all classes ?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu once for all tests and all classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JUnit's @BeforeClass annotation.

```
class Test {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void doOnce()
        //Do once before any test case is run.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

You can use inheritance or composition. E.g. you can create `TestBase` class:

```
class TestBase {
   @Before
   protected setUp() {
      // code for all tests
   }
}
```

and then your tests can derive from it:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
class SpecificTest extends TestBase {
   ...
}
```

**Solution #2**

You can also create some Utility class containing repeatable code in a method and call this method in every `setUp()` method in your tests. Then, you won't need inheritance. Example:

```
class Util {
   private Util() {}
   public static setUp() {
      // code for all tests
   }
}
```

and your test could look like that:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
class SpecificTest {
   @Before
   public setUp() {
      Util.setUp();
   }
}
```

Comment: but would that setUp method run every time that class that extends TestBase is tested? What I want is some event or method that executed just like @before but just once before any tests are executed of any class.

Comment: @AamirAbro try `beforeTest()` in `TestApplication` that implements `TestLifeCycleApplication`. See http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/